# Codeigniter Increase the execution time

Tags: php, codeigniter

I already increased the execution time of script in `php.ini` but seems like codeigniter neglect it and make my script stop after 30 seconds of execution.

I also googled how to increase the execution time of codeigniter and they say that its in the system core of codeigniter but when I checked, there's none to tweak. Must be because the version of my codeigniter is current.

I also added `ini_set('max_execution_time',0)` above my controller but no effect and so I put it inside the function but same outcome.

I also tried `set_time_limit(0)` above and before the script but none has gave good results....

Please help because I need process more than 3000 records  and it will take more than 10 minutes....

Comment: Have you restarted server(Apache or whatever you are running) after making changes at php.ini file ?

Comment: try restarting,if it still fails do post the code.

Comment: I cannot post my code because it's way too long but I will only just give some idea I extract the attendance first from a text file then sort it depending the scheduled time of employee lets say 8 to 5 then after that I also extract the overtime.....

Comment: I already edited php.ini to 15000 but it's like codeigniter ignores it...

Comment: I tried adding it in htacces but nothing has changed also.

Comment: I already tried adding the set_time_limit or the ini_set to main index.php but nothing helps....

Comment: I uploaded my codeigniter.php and this is the link "http://wikisend.com/download/458258/codeigniter.txt", hope you can help me with this problem...

Comment: I upload now also my code and here it is "http://wikisend.com/download/957948/script.txt" please check if the problem is in my code....

Answer (score 1):

Hello Try this code add this script in system/core/CodeIgniter.php

```
if (function_exists("set_time_limit") == TRUE AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == 0)
{
    @set_time_limit(300);
}
```

Comment: what if the set_time_limit does not exist will this code work? Because I already added it in my system/core/codeigniter.php but none has changed or should I put set_time_limit also on top of my controller?

Comment: my version of codeigniter is the latest so far version 3 and this code when I add it, seems like codeigniter remove this fix feature...

Comment: I uploaded my codeigniter.php and this is the link "http://wikisend.com/download/458258/codeigniter.txt", hope you can help me with this problem...

Comment: I upload now also my code and here it is "http://wikisend.com/download/957948/script.txt" please check if the problem is in my code....

Answer (score 0):

What type of php are you using? eg php5-fpm?

A better way of doing this would be to pull records in batches and process them,

Either set a cron job to pull 10 records and process every 5 minutes, or you could push them into a queueing system.

Unless you daemonising your php process it shouldnt be running this long, if its taking 3000 records 10mins it sounds quite memory exhaustive, you could run out of memory in this execution time so again batches are your best bet.

You also don't want to also have to set a 10 minute execution time on a production server as, it could be easily abused to tie up your system resources.

Comment: I upgraded my php to version 7

Comment: I uploaded my codeigniter.php and this is the link "http://wikisend.com/download/458258/codeigniter.txt", hope you can help me with this problem...

Comment: I upload now also my code and here it is "http://wikisend.com/download/957948/script.txt" please check if the problem is in my code....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my problem when I changed my sql query from model to this:

```
function get_Logs()
{
    $query = "SELECT EmpID, ValidDate, GROUP_CONCAT(ValidTime) AS LogTime FROM temp_logs GROUP BY EmpID,ValidDate";

    $result = $this->db->query($query);

    return $result->result_array();
}
```

Codeigniter query format somehow stops even though there's still records to be processed but by changing it to the native sql syntax structure, my script works as it should do.... Thanks very much for the people who post comments to my questions...