# Cannot load data and its count in CodeIgniter 3 because of taking too much time

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page in my website that shows a table of data with the total count of data. The data can be filtered in the table, and when the data is filtered, the count could change to match the data being filtered. The data is fetched from an Oracle DB view and there are 20000+ of them, but the table only shows the first 10 data.

To show the count and the data themselves, I use 2 separate methods from the data's model, let's call them `count_data` and `get_data`. In the controller's method, `count_data` is called first and returning the count of the data, then `get_data` is called and returning 10 data to be displayed.

```
<?php
class Record extends CI_Controller
    // ...
    function show_table() {
        // ...
        $recordCount = $this->record_model->count_data(/* arguments */);
        // ...
        $recordData = $this->record_model->get_data(/* arguments */);
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

The problem is, every time I try to load the page, the data won't load. It will only return error message about internet connection within 20 seconds. When I tried to modify `count_data` to return a hard-coded value, it worked, but even the data took around 20 seconds to load.

I've tried many ways to make my data load in my page. I've tried adding this script in script in system/core/CodeIgniter.php

```
if (function_exists("set_time_limit") == TRUE AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == 0)
{
    @set_time_limit(300);
}
```

I have added `ini_set('max_execution_time',0)` and `set_time_limit(0)` on my controller. I also have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409079/codeigniter-increase-the-execution-time) by changing the query from CodeIgniter like this

```
        $this->load->database();
        $this->db->from($this->view);
        $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
        $this->db->close();
        return $count;
```

To native like this

```
        $this->load->database();
        $result = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
        $count = $result[0]["TOTAL"];
        $this->db->close();
        return $count;
```

But it keeps failing. It still returns the error and no data in 20 seconds.

Please help me I'm running out of solution.

EDIT:

I suspect that this has something to do with the fact that:

- It has 79 columns.
- It's not a materialized view, so it can't be indexed.

This is because there are other views and tables in the database that have more rows than my view, but whose data are fetched much faster — less than 5 seconds. The views have column counts at most 1/2 of my view's, while the tables have indices.

Comment: How long does your SQL take when you run it outside of CI (in your preferred RDBMS)? Do you have optimal indexes in your schema? Is it less about time and more about memory? Do you have an extraordinarily huge amount of data in this table (which doesn't have a ridiculously high number of rows)?

Comment: @mickmackusa it takes 10 seconds outside of CI. Also sorry for saying it wrong in the question, the data is actually from a (non-materialized) view, not table, so it can't be indexed. The view has 79 columns.

Comment: Your are making two trips to the database.  What if you isolate the row counting query? Does it resolve if you just call `exit($this->record_model->count_data(......));` in your controller?

Comment: Like this? `$recordCount = exit($this->record_model->count_data(/* arguments */));` No, it doesn't resolve.

Comment: I don't want you to load a view or anything.  You don't need to save the returned model value to a variable.  `exit()` will echo the returned value and kill the execution from that point.  I want to know if your model can actually count the total rows in the view table.  Are there any errors in your logs?  We should also include some sanity checks like printing out all variables which are assumed to be correctly populated. I don't know if I endorse the variable naming of the view table as a class object `$this->view` ...that looks like a good candidate for conflicts with CI naming conventions.

Comment: Please excuse me for needing to confirm some "did you plug the computer in?" points... In your `Record_model.php` file, do you have `class Record_model extends MY_Model { public function __construct() { parent::__construct(); } public function count_data($yourFiltersToBeImplementedLater): int { return $this->db->count_all_results('your_view_table_name'); }`  Because I don't like "snake_case" in my applications, I typically load models with `$this->load->model('Record_model', 'RecordModel');` and call methods with `$this->RecordModel->countData($yourFilters);`

Comment: Yes, mine is like that, although my model extends `CI_Model`, and I got the count from one of the two last codes in the question.

Comment: Yes, `CI_Model` is right. Okay, please add `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` (in case you are hitting your memory limit) and then change your controller method to only call `exit($this->record_model->get_data(......));`. Again, check your logs if the script breaks.  Beyond this, I'll need to have a look at the actual controller and model methods to see if you have any "bad" code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255924/discussion-between-prido1024-and-mickmackusa).

Comment: Please share more detais. If a `SELECT` query takes too much time, what does the execution plan tell you about this? Having 79 columns in a single table sounds like you should normalize the table

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't understand which detail to share from the execution plan. What I understand is the view is made from joining around 5 to 7 tables, some of which are remote or from outside the database.

Comment: Any would help. Joining 5 to 7 tables is something that you haven't even mentioned yet. So checking the query that does the join for missing indexes should be the first thing to check when poor performances arises